# Aspose.Words Returning PDF as Stream does nothing (ASP.NET Web API)

Tags: asp.net, aspose.words

We are exploring using Aspose.Words for some conversions in an on premise API.

This works perfectly for Excel sheets using Aspose.Cells.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("convert/excel")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConvertExcel(IFormFile fileToConvert)
{
    var fileStream = new MemoryStream();
    fileToConvert.CopyTo(fileStream);
    var convertedFile = await pdfConverter.ConvertExcelAsync(fileStream);
    return File(convertedFile, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

However when using exactly the same method for Aspose.Words it does nothing, literally nothing just continues for a few minutes and then times out. This is not a timeout issue with the conversion as the file is 200KB.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("convert/word")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConvertWord(IFormFile fileToConvert)
{
    var fileStream = new MemoryStream();
    fileToConvert.CopyTo(fileStream);
    var convertedFile = await pdfConverter.ConvertWordAsync(fileStream);
    return File(convertedFile, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

I have tried various forms of returning a file but no luck.

```
return new FileStreamResult(convertedFile, "application/pdf");
```

The actual conversion methods look like this.

```
public Task<Stream> ConvertWordAsync(Stream fileStream)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ConvertWord(fileStream));
}

private Stream ConvertWord(Stream inputFile)
{
    var doc = new Document(inputFile);

    var outputFile = new MemoryStream();
    doc.Save(outputFile, Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Pdf);
    //doc.Save(@"C:\ProgramData\foo.pdf", Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Pdf); //THIS WORKS BUT NOT APPOPRIATE

    return outputFile;
}
```

I have also updated it to support HttpGet and hard-coded a path to a file and in browser just get a Download failed - network error.

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Factory.StartNew`? What advantage is that giving you here?

Comment: In this case... Not a lot. Originally we were going to take a collection of IFormFile and process them. I does not effect my issue I do not believe (will double check) as the Excel one is the same and is fine.

Comment: Then you should ditch it. It's complicating the code and not giving you any benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is possible that the Save method returns the memory stream at the end of the stream.

You should try the following immediately after the call to `doc.Save`

```
outputFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: Thank you!! I'm not overly familiar with Streams, any ideas why there would be a difference between Excel and Word? Or would this simply different behaviour in the Save methods between components?

Comment: It would seem that differences between Cells and Words is not unheard of: https://forum.aspose.com/t/inconsistency-in-handling-of-streams-between-words-and-cells/132270

Comment: Oh wow, that was posted in 2010, and clearly still an issue today! Thank you Patrick. :)